# Accidentally deleted vmail account

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am complete lost, this is urgent.

I accidentally deleted vmail account so now, dovecot isn't working nor postix (not able to receive mails). I don't want to re-install postix, I spent a lot of time to configure aith all stuff.

Can somebody give a hint?

Now dovecot says (mail.err)

```
Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Permission denied
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted user `vmail` account, you can re-create it preferably by specifying the original user id uid to avoid changing configuration or ownership of directories/files. You can use:

```
$ sudo useradd -d <vmail_home> -s <shell> -u <vmail_id> vmail
```

You need to specify the right values for home, shell, and user id.

Comment: but I don't know those values :( can I find them in logs or somewhere?

Comment: You can get them from your config and from mail directories owner id.

Comment: You can get lost user parameters from 3 backup files: `/etc/passwd-` `/etc/group-` `/etc/shadow-`. You can restore by copying these files.

Comment: Thank you all, seems that vmail account used /var/mail folder as HOME and when stupid delete that user, I deleted postfix home too. Now I lost all INBOX but changed to Maildir (from mbox) and everything is working. I have no idea who was creating that vmail account, probably some crappy tutorials used in the past for installing Roundcube or other, so vmail is actually not needed at all. I cannot vote, but thank you!

Comment: PS. I am not familiar with unix FS, since my inbox was in /var/mail there is a chance to recover that file if I re-created manually /var/mail several times? I mean if I look at HDD for user.name (file) and with some XXX Mb as size, directly on partition?

Comment: if you have a debian or ubuntu system you could try looking in /var/backups, at least debian keeps a copy of old password/shadow/group files in there